# How to count multiple columns in SQL (Oracle) with criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot

I'm working on SMS-Gateway that holds multiple charged SMS-services with different numbers,
each SMS sent to the customer has 4 status  as below (**forwarded, delivered, expired,delivery failed**)

[image]

Now I have the below first_table for the charging-system with the below details (**TABLE-A**)

[image]

and below (**TABLE-B**) which contain the status of each sent SMS with its ID
[image]

Below is my expected final result to forecast the details for each sms-service :

[image]

At first I thought it was easy all I need is just to use `COUNT(Case when ...)`
but in my case I have thousands of SMS-numbers(services) so if I use this approach it will be like that:-

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='1111' AND B.STATUS='forwarded' )
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='1111' AND B.STATUS='delivered' )
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='1111' AND B.STATUS='expired' )
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='1111' AND B.STATUS='delivery failed' )
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='5000' AND B.STATUS='forwarded' )
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='5000' AND B.STATUS='delivered' )
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='5000' AND B.STATUS='expired' )
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.SMS_SHORT_CODE='5000' AND B.STATUS='delivery failed' )
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
```

The above approach not practical when you have many services also noting that `CASE` can handle only 250 conditions?
So what is the best approach to do `left outer join` for (Table A) on (Table B) using the SMS-ID and count each SMS-status and forecast it as below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest conditional aggregation:

```
select b.SMS_SHORT_CODE,
       sum(case when status = 'forwaded' then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_forwaded,
       sum(case when status = 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_status,
       sum(case when status = 'expired' then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_expired,
       sum(case when status = 'delivery failed' then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_delivery_failed
from TABLEB b
group by b.SMS_SHORT_CODE ;
```

Note that no `JOIN` is necessary.  All the data you want to aggregate is in `TABLEB`.

Comment: thanks ,I will try, but I need table left outer join with table A because some-sms are free,TABLE A contain only the charged SMS's that's why I'm using the join .

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna . . . That is fine.  You can use a `left join`.  But it is not needed for the question that you *asked*.

Comment: I chose this approach because more simple and work other scenarios and less complex for me ,I think I need to learn about pivot also .

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query,

```
select 
A.SMS_SHORT_CODE,
case when status = 'forwaded' then count(status ) end as count_of_forwaded,
case when status = 'delivered' then count(status ) end as count_of_status,
case when status = 'expired' then count(status ) end as count_of_expired,
case when status = 'delivery failed' then count(status ) end as count_of_delivery_failed
from TABLEA A
inner join TABLEB B 
on (A.SMS_ID = B.SMS_ID)
group by A.SMS_SHORT_CODE, status ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PIVOT`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html) clause (*introduced in Oracle 11g version*) for those `status` columns :

```
SELECT sms_short_code, 
       COUNT_OF_forwarded, 
       COUNT_OF_delivered, 
       COUNT_OF_expired,
       COUNT_OF_delivery_failed
  FROM tableB
 PIVOT 
 (
  COUNT(*) FOR status IN ( 'forwarded'       AS COUNT_OF_forwarded,
                           'delivered'       AS COUNT_OF_delivered,
                           'expired'         AS COUNT_OF_expired,
                           'delivery failed' AS COUNT_OF_delivery_failed )
 )
```

e.g. only using `TableB` is enough.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce09e70756d919703c66a402d1b93679)</kbd>

Comment: thanks Barbaros Özhan ,I will try, but I need table left outer join with table A because some-sms are free,TABLE A contain only the charged SMS's that's why I'm using the join .

Comment: you're welcome @OsamaAl-Banna , but need to extend the output set as desired and elaborate the question more by editing it.